# Rail Devise sign_up/forgot_password in same view - Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a signin view that contains two partials from the devise default views that I renamed as:
1. _sign_in.html.erb
2. _forgot.html.erb

I am overriding the devise passwords controller:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def create 
  # super

  self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)
  yield resource if block_given?

  if successfully_sent?(resource)
   respond_with({}, location: after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
  else
   render signin_path

   # Original redirect
   # respond_with(resource)
  end
 end
end
```

The partial code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

   <div class="form-inputs">
   <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Please enter your email address', label: false %>
```

```
   <div class="form-actions">
     <%= f.button :submit, "Send me instructions to reset my password ", class: "btn-wide secondary" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the signin.html.erb view that both partials are rendered from:

```
<div class="hero">
  <%= image_tag("key-logo.png", :class => "logo", :alt => "key-logo") %>
  <h1>App.title</h1>
  <div class="sign-in">
    <%= render "devise/sessions/sign_in" %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sign-up">
  <div class="intro">
    <h1><a name="signupform">Forgot your password?</a></h1>
    <h3>Don't worry it happens to the best of us. We got this.</h3>
    <h5>Just enter your email in the form below and you're set!</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="forgot">
      <%= render "devise/passwords/forgot" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I've configured the routes accordlingly:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'registrations',
    passwords: 'passwords'
  }

  get 'pages/index'
  get 'docs', to: 'pages#docs', as: 'docs'
  get 'signin', to: 'pages#signin', as: 'signin'

  root to: 'pages#index'
end
```

I've configured the devise user scope in application.helper as:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    # Fix to get devise forms working within the application scope and not just the gem:
  # http://pupeno.com/2010/08/29/show-a-devise-log-in-form-in-another-page/
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

  def day
    @day = Time.now
    @day.strftime('%A')
  end

end
```

When I submit I am getting a missing template error:

```
Missing template /signin with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: *
```

I know the devise specs state to re-create the corresponding view in the views directory. I've tried that and still get the error. I wondered if it was a problem with the form namespace. I am using simple_forms to render my forms.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with this in the routes

```
get 'signin', to: 'pages#signin', as: 'signin'
```

when I changed it back to the original

```
get 'pages/signin'
```

it worked